# How to parse two space-delimited numbers with thousand separator?

Tags: javascript, string-parsing

I need to parse string that contains two numbers that may be in three cases :

`"646.60 25.10" => [646.60 25.10]`

`"1 395.86 13.50" => [1395.86, 13.50]`

`"13.50 1 783.69" => [13.50, 1 783.69]`

In a simple case it's enough use `'number'.join(' ')` but in the some cases there is thousand separator like in second and third ones.

So how could I parse there numbers for all cases?

**EDIT:** All numbers have a decimal separator in the last segment of a number.

Comment: Is that third example correct? You've said they're space-delimited, but there's a `=>` in the third example.

Comment: Is `"1 350 467"` a possible input value? Or can you rely on having a decimal point of some kind (whether `,` or `.`). If `"1 350 467"` is a possible input, the task is impossible. It might be `[1350, 467]` or it might be `[1, 350467]`.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder I've edited the post, thx for noting. No it's not possible value because I have `.` in number even for `12.00` number

Comment: @Erik is 1-digit number always considered as a thousand or it could be just that number?

Comment: @Mikelis Baltruks it could be just number. I may also have `2 980.05`, `12 980.05` numbers

Comment: @Erik: Your comment to Mikelis just now flatly contradicts your comment to me just now. Do you, or do you not, *reliably* have a decimal separator in the last segment of a number? Separately, are you guaranteed not to have a thousands separator? And what does your second example result `[1395.86, 13,50]` mean? (Note the comma.)

Comment: so how do you imagine detecting if `1 234 567` is `[1234, 567]` or `[1, 234567]`

Comment: OHH. I get it. every number ends with ...POINT-DIGIT-DIGIT. xD

Comment: @T.J. Crowder sorry, I've updated the comment. Yes I have a decimal separator in the last segment of a number every time

Comment: And the other questions in that comment? In particular, the question about thousands separators, since your inputs seem to have both `,` and `.` as a decimal separator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var string1 = "646.60 25.10";// => [646.60 25.10]

var string2 = "1 395.86 13,50";// => [1395.86, 13,50]

var string3 = "13.50 1 783.69"; // => [13.50, 1 783.69]


function getArray(s) {
var index = s.indexOf(" ", s.indexOf("."));
 return [s.substring(0,index), s.substring(index+1) ];
}


console.log(getArray(string1));
console.log(getArray(string2));
console.log(getArray(string3));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming every number ends with a dot-digit-digit (in the comments you said they do), you can use that to target the right place to split with aregex.
That way, it is robust and general for any number of numbers (although you specified you have only two) and for any number of digits in the numbers, as long as it ends with the digit-dot-digit-digit:

```
str1 = "4 435.89 1 333 456.90 7.54";

function splitToNumbers(str){
  arr = str.replace(/\s+/g,'').split(/(\d+.\d\d)/);
  //now clear the empty strings however you like
  arr.shift();
  arr.pop();
  arr = arr.join('&').split(/&+/);

 return arr;
}

console.log(splitToNumbers(str1));
//4435.89,1333456.90,7.54
```